# Adjust lvm2 cache block size

Tags: linux, lvm

I see the following message in my syslog:

```
[    6.774422] device-mapper: cache: You have created a cache device with a lot of individual cache blocks (1933312)
               All these mappings can consume a lot of kernel memory, and take some time to read/write.
               Please consider increasing the cache block size to reduce the overall cache block count.
```

However, I can not find documentation about how to adjust the block size without disabling, recreating and enabling the cache...

Is this the proper way or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the LVM blocksize, what happens is the following:

To use a partition, LVM volume or even a file as swap at `swapon` time the  kernel generates a map of swap offset -> disk blocks and from then on the kernel uses uses that map to perform swap I/O directly against the actual disk queue for swap. That allows the kernel to by-pass  lot of file-system, meta data, LVM, caching operations for swap access.

At the moment you LVM volume is not contiguous, which means that the actual disk blocks used by your swap LVM volume are spread out over the underlying physical  disk(s), which is inefficient and that triggers the warning you're seeing, your swap consists of a large number of individual bits of disk, rather than a section of disk.

You can try to modify your LVM volume with the [`lvchange`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lvchange) flag **`-C y`**. That will change the policy to contiguous.

> **`-C`**, **`--contiguous {y|n}`**
>   Tries to set or reset the contiguous allocation policy for logical volumes. It's only possible to change a non-contiguous logical volume's allocation policy to contiguous, if all of the allocated physical extents are already contiguous.

You may need to actually re-create the LVM volume if the physical extends are not already contiguous, [`lvcreate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lvcreate) supports the same  **`-C y`**, **`--contiguous y`** flags.

Comment: Do I do this for all logical volumes or just the cache one?

Comment: @der_michael Only for the swap volume